# Need to transfert on network more than 3G of little file

Tags: c#, networking, directory, compression

I need to transfer lots of little files on the network. The total size of my files is about 3G and will grow in the future. I know if i transfert the files in one file like (winrar file, winzip file or 7 zipfile) the performance will be better on the network, but i will pay later on cpu time to compress and uncompress the file.

Is there a way in c# of transfert my directory in only one file witout use third party like winrar, winzip, 7zip ....

What will be the best way to transfert my folder, subfolder and file with the best performance ?

Rigth now i use a custom method to do it cause the `Directory.Move` give me some problem

There is my actual method, I know it probably not the most performance transfert method. Any suggestion ?

The question is :

**How i could transfert all my directory and files with the better performance including compression and decompression (if i need it) on a network share in c# ?**

```
private void CopyDirectory(string source, string destination)
    {
      string[] files;


      if (!Directory.Exists(destination)) DirectoryHelper.CreateDirectoriesFromPath(destination);

      files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(source);

      foreach (string fileElement in files)
      {
        if (Directory.Exists(fileElement))
        {
          if (!ExcludedDirectoryName.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileElement)))
          {
            CopyDirectory(fileElement, Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(fileElement)));
          }
        }
        else
        {
          try
          {
            // Valide si le fichier fait partie de la liste d'exclusion
            if (!ExcludedDirectoryName.Contains(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileElement)))
            {
              // Calcule le Path de destination
              string destinationFile = Path.Combine(destination, Path.GetFileName(fileElement));

              // Valide si le fichier existe
              if (FileHelper.Exist(destinationFile))
              {
                // Supprime le fichier
                File.Delete(destinationFile);
              }

              // Copie le nouveau fichier
              File.Copy(fileElement, destinationFile, true);
            }
          }
          catch (IOException ioEx)
          {


            // Log l'exception
            ExceptionLogger.Publish(ioEx);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: leppie, sorry there is my question : How i could transfert all my directory and files with the better performance including compression and decompression (if i need it) on a network share in c# ?

Comment: Performance, as usual, it is an ambiguous word. Do you mean 'in the less time possible using all the pc resources' or do you mean 'with less impact on pc availability using the spare time when the pc is iddle'.

Comment: I need to do it in the less time possible.

Answer (score 0):

An archive format like zip has a lot of advantages over file-by-file transfer, especially if you are handling many tens of thousands of small files.  For one thing, zip is completely debugged. You won't have to worry about edge cases like empty files or directories. For another thing, transferring a few large files over a network takes far less overhead than transferring lots of little ones.

There is a lot of overhead per file both on the file system from which you are getting your files and the file system that receives them. There is simply nothing you can do about this overhead except when you create the file systems (when you can set an appropriate block and cluster size).

Using an archiving package like DotNetZip inside your program may help.  You'll be able to write, and then read, zip files under control of your program. Check it out.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181291/DotNetZip. Sharpziplib is also a possibility.

But, you may want to look into using a tool like rsync. This is purpose built for what you're doing and it is completely debugged.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync